# Confusion in use of a notation in Smooth Manifolds

Tags: analysis, notation, smooth-manifolds

I am self studying Smooth manifolds from Notes of a senior and I am having a confusion in following notation:

> Regular value theorem is stated as following: Let $f: M^n \to N^m$ be smooth. Suppose that $q\in N$ is a regular value for f and ie $df_P : T_P M \to T_Q N$ is surjective for all $P\in f^{-1}(q)$. Then $f^{-1}(q) $ is  a submanifold of M of dimension n-m.

"$f: M^n \to N^m$ be smooth" Here there are powers on M and N both( n and m respectively)
while   in   "$df_P : T_P M \to T_Q N$"there are no powers on N and M.

I think in "$f: M^n \to N^m$ be smooth" they specify the dimension of manifolds and once the dimension is given , so there is no need to specify the dimension again and hence It was written only in terms of M and N again in "$df_P : T_P M \to T_Q N$".

But This is just my guess. If it is wrong , kindly specify the right notation.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Yes, the superscript indicates the dimension (I'm not a fan of such notation, but that's the way it is). The following is how I'd say it "Let $M,N$ be smooth manifolds, $f:M\to N$ a smooth map and $q\in N$ a regular value for $f$ (i.e for every $p\in f^{-1}(\{q\})$, $df_p:T_pM\to T_{f(p)}N$ is surjective). Then, $f^{-1}(\{q\})$ is a submanifold of $M$ of dimension $\dim M-\dim N$".